# Is there a special case of the EM algorithm for exponential family distributions?

Tags: expectation-maximization, exponential-family

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Description), the formal definition of the EM algorithm is

> The EM algorithm seeks to find the MLE of the marginal likelihood by iteratively applying these two steps:
>
> *Expectation step (E step)*: Define $Q(\boldsymbol\theta\mid\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)})$ as the expected value of the log likelihood function of $\boldsymbol\theta$, with respect to the current conditional distribution of $\mathbf{Z}$ given $\mathbf{X}$ and the current estimates of the parameters $\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}$:
> $$
> Q(\boldsymbol\theta\mid\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}) = \operatorname{E}_{\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{X},\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}}\left[ \log L (\boldsymbol\theta; \mathbf{X},\mathbf{Z})  \right] \,
> $$
>
> *Maximization step (M step)*: Find the parameters that maximize this quantity:
> $$
> \boldsymbol\theta^{(t+1)} = \underset{\boldsymbol\theta}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} \ Q(\boldsymbol\theta\mid\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}) \,
> $$

In instances where $p(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$ is an exponential family distribution, I have found that authors used
$$
Q(\boldsymbol\theta\mid\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}) = \log L (\boldsymbol\theta; \mathbf{X},\operatorname{E}_{\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{X},\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}}\left[\mathbf{Z}\right]) \,
$$
instead of
$$
Q(\boldsymbol\theta\mid\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}) = \operatorname{E}_{\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{X},\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}}\left[ \log L (\boldsymbol\theta; \mathbf{X},\mathbf{Z})  \right] \,
$$
where $\operatorname{E}_{\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{X},\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}}\left[\mathbf{Z}\right]$ is the estimated data. Are these two equations equivalent?

Comment: This seems like a type error to me. In the former, you're taking an expectation over all possible Z's. Z can be of any type; e.g. a tree or set. But in the latter, you're taking the expected value. But what's an 'expected tree'? It only makes sense if Z is a continuous value. (And even then, I'm not sure this is what you _want_ to do. If you took the mode value instead of the mean, you'd recover Viterbi EM.)

Comment: Is this an abridged version of your question here? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/547900/155836

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy "In the former, you're taking an expectation over all possible Z's. Z can be of any type; e.g. a tree or set. But in the latter, you're taking the expected value." not sure what the difference between "expectation over all possible Z's" and "expected value" is here, could you explain? As for your second comment, yes you're right. The longer version of this question was accidentally submitted. Not sure why. I deleted it.

Comment: Oh, there's no distinction. I wrote poorly. You're feeding the expected value into the likelihood function, instead of a given value. But certain types don't have an expected value.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy what if I assume that $\operatorname{E}_{\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{X},\boldsymbol\theta^{(t)}}\left[\mathbf{Z}\right]$ is always defined? Would the two equations be equivalent then? I'm mainly asking this because I have rarely seen the first equation used in practice, while I've seen the second many times. It seems the first equation is only good for demonstrating that this is the lower-bound for the evidence, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we want to estimate the parameter $\theta$ of the distribution $p(z;\theta)$ of a random variable $Z$. If we had samples $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N$, we could easily do this using maximum likelihood estimation. However, suppose instead we are given the samples $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ of another random variable $X$, where $X$ and $Z$ are related via the joint distribution $p(x,z)$. Since $p(x,z) = p(x \mid z) \cdot p(z;\theta)$, then $p(x,z) = p(x,z;\theta)$.

We could then define the *complete-data likelihood* as
$$
p(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N,z_1,z_2,\dots,z_N)
$$
We can also assume that each pair $(x_i,z_i)$ is independent of and identically distributed to every other pair for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,N\}$ such that
$$
p(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N,z_1,z_2,\dots,z_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N p(x_i,z_i;\theta)
$$
and
$$
\log p(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N,z_1,z_2,\dots,z_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N \log p(x_i,z_i;\theta)
$$
Next, let
$$
p(x_i,z_i;\theta) = h(x_i,z_i) \cdot \exp(\eta (\theta) \cdot T(x_i,z_i) + A(\theta))
$$
such that
$$
\log p(x_i,z_i;\theta) = \log h(x_i,z_i) + \eta (\theta) \cdot T(x_i,z_i) + A(\theta)
$$
Then, note that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\log p(x_i,z_i;\theta) \mid x_i\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\log h(x_i,z_i) \mid x_i\right] + \eta (\theta) \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[T(x_i,z_i) \mid x_i\right] + A(\theta) \\
\log p(x_i,\mathbb{E}\left[z_i \mid x_i\right];\theta) &= \log h(x_i,\mathbb{E}\left[z_i \mid x_i\right]) + \eta (\theta) \cdot T(x_i,\mathbb{E}\left[z_i \mid x_i\right]) + A(\theta)
\end{align}
and so, in general,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\log p(x_i,z_i;\theta) \mid x_i\right] \neq \log p(x_i,\mathbb{E}\left[z_i \mid x_i\right];\theta)
$$